# What is the DC component of the sum of phasors?

Tags: dc, signal, phasor

I am preparing for the written test conducted by IISc Bangalore for admission into their graduate program. I happened to come across a [sample paper](https://ece.iisc.ac.in/images/talks/SampleQuestionPaperInterviews.pdf) from 2016, I think.

I am struggling to understand the 11th question,

[image: q11]

Since phasors are sinusoids, I think the answer is 0. But, here they called it a "time signal" and specified a finite time range.

So even if I considered a windowed version of the periodic signal, then since [the Fourier transform of the signal at 0 frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21583/difference-between-dc-component-and-zero-frequency-component-of-signal) is finite, I can conclude the time average value is still 0.

So my question is, what is the answer? which of my interpretation would be correct? Also how can complex signals be "time signals", is there any physical interpretation of "dc component" of sum of spinning phasors?

Comment: In time T, how many cycles of the first signal? how many cycles of the 2nd signal? are the # of cycles EXACTLY integer? by the way, signals happen in time, not in frequency.

Comment: I don't think your Fourier transform argument  about "finite" has relevance.

Comment: I'm not clear why phasors should be involved in this question at all. This is a time domain representation of the signal, not a phasor representation. (And if there is a way to represent signals with multiple frequency components as phasors, I was never taught it)

Comment: It's the DC component of the Fourier series expansion of x(t), which is zero. Phasors are not relevant.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf in the other stackexchange answer I linked, they defined the DC value of a signal in such a way that the numerator would be F(0), so that's why I made that argument. I understand your idea about it being exactly integer. Let me try that.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I now realise phasors are not relevant here at all. I was trying to visualise this sum and thought of phasors. But phasors only work with a single frequency like Photon said.

Comment: But I'm still not clear on how a time signal can be a complex function of time. It's not physically realisable right?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf so the answer is Zero because exactly 2 cycles of $3e^{j2wt}$ and 3 cycles of $4e^{3jwt}$ happens  in that T time. So because it's a complete cycle, no DC component.

Comment: Integrate the function between 0 and \$2\pi /\omega_0\$. This gives zero, hence DC component is zero.